# Hot Swapping Webapp Files

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running my application in production mode (war is not exploded) on a Glassfish server and I want to know if it's possible to hot swap my front end files?

Currently when I do a hot swap, it only does it in the backend (it being Java). Is it possible to also do it for files under the webapp directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Run/Debug Configuration` window for Glassfish-within-IntelliJ supports hot deployment:

> For exploded artifacts, the available options are:
>
> **Update resources**. All changed resources are updated (HTML, JSP, JavaScript, CSS and image files).
>
> **Update classes and resources**. Changed resources are updated; changed Java classes (EJBs, servlets, etc.) are recompiled.
>
> etc

Looks like you need to choose the `Update Resources` option.

More details [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-glassfish-server.html).

**Update 1:** for packed (i.e. unexploded) artifacts the available options are:

> **Hot swap classes**. Changed classes are recompiled and reloaded at runtime. This option works only in the debug mode.
>
> **Redeploy**. The application artifact is rebuilt and redeployed.
>
> **Restart server**. The server is restarted. The application artifact is rebuilt and redeployed.

There is no support for hot deploying 'front end files' in a unexploded artifact.

Comment: That's working fine for me when my build is development  (exploded artifact). But I am wondering whether it's still possible to do it when it's NOT an exploded artifact? It woks to hot swap my java classes (backend) but it doesn't pick up any changes under the webapp directory (frontend).

Comment: Apologies, when I read this: _"my application in production mode (war is not exploded) on a Glassfish server and I want to know if it's possible to hot swap my front end files"_ I assumed you were running an exploded artifact. I have now updated the answer to describe the available actions for unexploded artifacts. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah damn that's a bit disappointing, oh well. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: i use the 2 way but reloading does not work !!! this work on Netbeans correctly !!